# Простая форма ввода данных

Tags: php, html

Как сделать правильный вид?

```
<?php
echo "Привет, $_GET['name']  Вам $_GET['age'] лет ";
?>
```

Второй файл

```
<html><body>
<form action="lost.php" method="post">
Введите имя: <input type=text name="name"><br>
Введите возраст: <input type=text name="age"><br>
<input type=submit value="GO!">
</form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: @bekzat, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Почему-то когда удалил в строке "Введите возраст" команду isset, то возраст стал отображаться корректно

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
echo "Привет, $_POST['name']  Вам $_POST['age'] лет ";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="lost.php" method="get">
```

**POST** на **GET** поменять!

Comment: Два варианты решения, и оба правильные))

Comment: ну так то да...

Answer (score 1):

...а вообще отучайтесь без нужды вставлять переменные в строки. Привыкнете - будут непонятки с объектами и ключами массивов. Плюс не пускайте переменные без проверки.

```
<?php
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : 'Unknown';
$age = isset($_POST['age']) and $_POST['age'] > 0 ? (int) $_POST['age'] : 'Unknown';
echo 'Привет,' . $name . ',  Вам ' . $age . ' лет ';
?>

<html><body>
<form action="lost.php" method="post">
Введите имя: <input type=text name="name"><br>
Введите возраст: <input type=text name="age"><br>
<input type=submit value="GO!">
</form>
</body></html>
```

Примерно так)

Answer (score 0):

Кстати на заметку: есть ещё суперглобальный массив $_REQUEST который содержит $_GET и $POST. 
Его используют наверно редко - в техслучаях когда неважно как передаются параметры

Comment: Нет его используют просто для проверки передались ли какие-нибудь параметры или нет :)